# read csv file with mixed end of line

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io

I have a csv file with mixed line endings of '\n' and '\r\n'. When using csvread, csvread will report error, and when using textscan, textscan will only scan in the contents before the line ending character changes.
how do I input this file within matlab without preprocessing the file to fix the line endings?

example file:

```
 fid = fopen('ex1.csv', 'w');
 fprintf(fid, 'A,B,C\n');
fprintf(fid, '1,1,1\n');
 fprintf(fid, '2,2,2\r\n');
fprintf(fid, '3,3,3\r\n');
fclose(fid);
```

Note that the headline limits the use of `load`, and the `importdata` will miss the last row.

Comment: If only the headline is problematic, then you can place a `%` at the beginning of the line.  MATLAB will then treat it as a comment, and `load` will work.

Comment: @JeffIrwin Alternatively, just open the file in the Matlab Editor and save it back; it automatically converts to the proper EOL (at least on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

With the new sample input I can confirm that none of the built-in methods work desirably. Here's a solution using `textscan` and `reshape`:

```
fid = fopen('ex1.csv');
inputMatrix = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid);
inputMatrix = reshape(a{1}, 3, [])';    %'//assuming 3 columns in file

>> inputMatrix 
    'A'    'B'    'C'       
    '1'    '1'    '1'       
    '2'    '2'    [1x2 char]    %//the 2nd char is "\r"
    '3'    '3'    [1x2 char]
```

Alternatively, I usually just revert to the old fashioned way of reading files when convenient functions don't work:

```
fid = fopen('ex1.csv');
inputMatrix = {};
while ~feof(fid)
    line = fgetl(fid);
    inputMatrix(end+1,:) = strsplit(line, ',');
end
fclose(fid);

>> inputMatrix
inputMatrix = 
    'A'    'B'    'C'
    '1'    '1'    '1'
    '2'    '2'    '2'
    '3'    '3'    '3'
```

Note that this has the advantage of not caring about how many columns there are, and it also doesn't include `\r`.

In any case, you probably want the numbers to be a numeric matrix rather than a cell matrix of strings. A simple call to `str2double` will do this for you (and it will cleverly ignore any `\r`):

```
str2double(inputMatrix(2:end,:))
```

---

**Previous**

Without a sample file I can only make suggestions based on simple input I created locally, and it seems to me that both `importdata` and `load` work, depending on how your input data is structured.

Example input 1:

```
>> fid = fopen('ex1.csv', 'w');
>> fprintf(fid, '1,1,1\n');
>> fprintf(fid, '2,2,2\r\n');
>> fprintf(fid, '3,3,3\n');
>> fclose(fid);

>> a = importdata('ex1.csv')
ans = 
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
>> a = load('ex1.csv')
ans = 
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```

Example input 2:

```
>> fid = fopen('ex2.csv', 'w');
>> fprintf(fid, '1,1,1\n');
>> fprintf(fid, '2,2,2\r\n');
>> fprintf(fid, '3,3\n');
>> fclose(fid);

>> a = importdata('ex2.csv')
ans = 
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     NaN
>> a = load('ex2.csv')
Error using load
Number of columns on line 3 of ASCII file ex2.csv must be the same as previous lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up with

```
fid = fopen('ex1.csv');
inputMatrix = cell2mat(textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%*[^\n]', 'delimiter', ',','headerLines',1));
fclose(fid);


>> inputMatrix

inputMatrix =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```